# Python Script to Create Outlook .msg File

Tags: python, outlook

Is there a way to create an Outlook .msg file using Python? I want to generate several .msg files but with different data in the subject line. All the modules I have found are only for parsing already created .msg files.

Comment: Also to the people saying this is too broad, I disagree.. I cannot offer any specific modules because I cannot see if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly in Python, but you can either explicitly create an MSG file from the scratch (it format is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx)) or use a wrapper like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) - it is a regular COM object and can be used in Python using `win32com.client.Dispatch`. In VB:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  set Msg = Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile("C:\Temp\test.msg")
  Msg.Sent = true
  Msg.Subject = "test"
  Msg.Body = "test body"
  Msg.Save
```

Comment: How would I attach a file?

Comment: RDOMail.Attachments.Add