# Create .msg file with task without having outlook installed

Tags: python, django, outlook, msg

Is there any chance to create a outlook .msg file without having outlook installed.

We use a django backend and need to create a msg file containing a task for importing in outlook. Since we use unix-based servers we dont have any chance to get outlook installed (except wine etc..)

Is there a component to generate such .msg files in any programming language without having outlook installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Script to Create Outlook .msg File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614379/python-script-to-create-outlook-msg-file)

Comment: This required a) windows and b) outlook installed on the same machine. So unfortunately no solution

Answer (score 1):

Well the MSG file format is defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx but like all microsoft documention it's anything but readable. All you need to do is to write a bit of python code to produce a file that fits the given format.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an EML file? It is MIME, so there are hundreds of libraries out there. Outlook will be able to open an EML file just fine.

In your particular case, create a MIME file with the vTodo MIME part as the primary MIME part.

Comment: Interesting solution. Can explain further? Older versions of outlook cannot open ics-files / plain vtodo. AFAIK they need to be wrapped in a msg-file to be opened. Could you provide a sample?

Comment: Actually it looks like Outlook does no handle VTODO files, only VCALENDAR... So MSG file is your only option.